# How to include an argument while requesting for api in django?

Tags: django, api

I am trying to fatch live cricket score from sportsmonk cricket api and cricapi. using Django
everything goes fine until I request for any endpoint with a unique Id that is stored in a variable.

it gives key error always while doing so

my request :

```py
resL = json.loads(requests.get(
      'https://cricket.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/fixtures/id?api_token').text)
```

here 'id' is a variable for a particular fixture.
It works fine while putting any numerical value instead of a variable.

Same is the case with this url :

```py
resS = json.loads(requests.get(
      'http://cricapi.com/api/fantasySummary/?apikey=123&unique_id=id).text)
```

I not getting what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indicate that the `id` param in your url is a variable. The way you have it written, it's just a string with the characters `id`.

One way to accomplish this is with f-strings:

```
id = 543 # or whatever your id is
api_token = 123

resL = json.loads(requests.get(
       f'https://cricket.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/fixtures/{id}?apikey= 
       {api_token}').text)

resS = json.loads(requests.get(
       f'http://cricapi.com/api/fantasySummary/?apikey={api_token}&unique_id= 
       {id}).text)
```

When python parses these strings, it will replace {id} with the id you've defined as a variable elsewhere. Please note that you have to include the `f` at the beginning of the string.

Another way is with the older 'str'.format() method, which works as follows:

```
id = 543 # or whatever your id is
api_token = 123

resL = json.loads(requests.get(
       'https://cricket.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/fixtures/{}?apikey= 
       {}'.format(id, api_token)).text)

resS = json.loads(requests.get(
       'http://cricapi.com/api/fantasySummary/?apikey={}&unique_id= 
       {}'.format(id, api_token)).text)
```

Here, the variables in the format() function will be substituted into the empty brackets in order. (you do not need the f here)

Comment: It's working fine with your solution.Thanks a lot

Comment: no problem, could you accept my answer? thank you!